# Which of the Banach space $\ell^1(2), \ell^2(2),$ $\ell^\infty(2)$ are isometrically isomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve hte following question:

For $n \geq 1$ let $\ell^1(n), \ell^2(n), \ell^\infty(n)$ be the Banach Space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the norm
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|, \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\right)^{1/2}, \sup_{i=1,...,n}|x_i|$$
respectively. Answer the following questions and prove your assertions:

(a) Which of the Banach space $\ell^1(2), \ell^2(2),$ $\ell^\infty(2)$ are isometrically isomorphic?

**My attempt at a solution:**

We shall show that $\ell^\infty(2)$ is not ismetrically isomorphic to $\ell^1(2)$. Suppose otherwise and there existed a linear surjective $T$ such that $\norm{T(x_1, x_2)}_{\ell^1(2)}= \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$. Then we have $\norm{T(1,0)}_{\ell^1(2)} = \norm{T(0, 1)}_{\ell^1(2)} = \max(0, 1) = 1$.
**From here I wanted to deduce the form of $T$ and derive a contradiction**

(b) Which of the Banach space $\ell^1(3), \ell^2(3),$ $\ell^\infty(3)$ are isometrically isomorphic?

**According to [https://planetmath.org/isometricisomorphism#:~:text=A%20surjective%20linear%20map%20T,said%20to%20be%20isometrically%20isomorphic](https://planetmath.org/isometricisomorphism#:%7E:text=A%20surjective%20linear%20map%20T,said%20to%20be%20isometrically%20isomorphic). a isometric isomorphism is a map $T: X \to Y$ that is surjective linear map and preserves norm. What about the inverse map $T^{-1}: Y \to X$. Do we need to show both or does one imply the other?**

Comment: From my memory: Hilbert ($L^2,l^2)$. are what you want.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: The questions were similar and i didn't think it was worth making them separate posts

Comment: In fact $\ell^\infty(2)$ *is* isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1(2)$.  To see why and what the isomorphism might be, sketch the unit sphere of each one.

Comment: To show $\ell^2(2)$ is different, you could look up the "parallelogram law".

Comment: For $\ell^1(2), \ell^2(2),\ell^\infty(2)$, draw pictures of the unit balls.  [In two-dimensional space, that should be easy.]  Then ask yourself whether there are linear transformations that map one of those balls onto another.  I am repeating Nate's comment!  For three dimensions, it may be more challenging to find the balls, but you can still do it that way.  How can you show that the cube cannot be mapped onto the octahedron by a linear transformation?

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought we would required injectivity as well, but the isometric condition is sufficient to prove that such a linear map must be injective as well. Otherwise if $T(x) = T(y)$ then $T(x - y) = 0$, so that $||T(x-y)|| = 0$ while $||x - y|| \neq 0$ which is a contradiction

Comment: Yes, whence my "one (clearly!) implies the other". And apologies for my mistaken "none" for a and b based on a too hasty reading of https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_de_Banach-Mazur#Propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s